# How can I get all the members of Given group Id of Given List Id from MailChimp API?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mailchimp

I am try to fetch the all list of members subscribe to given list for given Group from MailChip API.

I  have two list in MailChimp.

1) Master List

```
   Groups: Group1, Group2
```

2) Test List

All user will be subscribe to each Group1, Group2 for List "Master List"
Now I want to fetch all the members of "Master List" Who has subscribe for "Group1" ONLY.

So, Which API Method I can use to fetch all?

My Code:

```
$result = $mailChimp->listMembers( $listid, $status );
```

This will give me all the data from given list but I want to get specific Groups data any idea how can i get?

> API Detail: listMembers – v1.3

```
listMembers(string apikey, string id, string status, string since, int start, int limit, string sort_dir)
```

Get all of the list members for a list that are of a particular status. Are you trying to get a dump including lots of merge data or specific members of a list?

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/searchmembers.func.php) might solve your problem. If your API wrapper does not contain this function, add it as follows:

```
function searchMembers(string query, string id, int offset=0) {
    $params = array();
    $params["query"] = $query;
    $params["id"] = $id;
    $params["offset"] = $offset;
    return $this->callServer("searchMembers", $params);
}
```

Not sure this will solve your problem or not, but this will surly get you started...

Comment: Thanks I will try this and check I hope it is working for me based on Group Search.

Comment: this should be in the same file where listMembers is defined

Comment: Let me check the function.

Comment: Error return:

`Array
(
    [errorCode] => -90
    [errorMessage] => Method searchMembers is not exported by this server
)`

Comment: I got answer why it is not working i am using mailchimp api version 1.2 I have changed from 1.2 to 1.3 and it is give me search list.